# Change the position of infoWindow appears in Google map API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I' m using google map api version 3 for this program. What I m trying to do is change the position of infoWindow which appears on mouseover. Currently it shows on the marker. I want to change the position to show it on top of the marker icon. When I replace

```
 speedTest.infoWindow.setPosition(latlng);
 speedTest.infoWindow.open(speedTest.map);
```

These two lines with following line,

```
 speedTest.infoWindow.open(speedTest.map, this);
```

It shows correctly on top of the marker. but then infoWindow will not able popup when I trigger mouse event from side items.

```
    speedTest.showMarkers = function() {
  speedTest.markers = [];

  var type = 1;
  if ($('usegmm').checked) {
    type = 0;
  }

  if (speedTest.markerClusterer) {
    speedTest.markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
  }

  var panel = $('markerlist');
  panel.innerHTML = '';
  var numMarkers = $('nummarkers').value;

  for (var i = 0; i < numMarkers; i++) {
    var titleText = speedTest.pics[i].photo_title;
    if (titleText == '') {
      titleText = 'No title';
    }

    var item = document.createElement('DIV');
    var title = document.createElement('A');
    title.href = '#';
    title.className = 'title';
    title.innerHTML = titleText;

    item.appendChild(title);
    panel.appendChild(item);


    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(speedTest.pics[i].latitude,
        speedTest.pics[i].longitude);

    var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&chco=' +
        'FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
        new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      'position': latLng,
      'icon': markerImage
    });

    var fn = speedTest.markerClickFunction(speedTest.pics[i], latLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', fn);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(title, 'click', fn);
    speedTest.markers.push(marker);
  }

  window.setTimeout(speedTest.time, 0);
};

speedTest.markerClickFunction = function(pic, latlng) {
  return function(e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    var title = pic.photo_title;
    var url = pic.photo_url;
    var fileurl = pic.photo_file_url;

    var infoHtml = '<div class="info"><h3>' + title +
      '</h3><div class="info-body">' +
      '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><img src="' +
      fileurl + '" class="info-img"/></a></div>' +
      '<a href="http://www.panoramio.com/" target="_blank">' +
      '<img src="http://maps.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/' +
      'iw_panoramio.png"/></a><br/>' +
      '<a href="' + pic.owner_url + '" target="_blank">' + pic.owner_name +
      '</a></div></div>';

    speedTest.infoWindow.setContent(infoHtml);
    speedTest.infoWindow.setPosition(latlng);
    speedTest.infoWindow.open(speedTest.map);
  };
};
```

Here is the full code I m currently using:

[speed_test_example.html](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0.2/examples/speed_test_example.html)

[speed_test.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0.2/examples/speed_test.js)

Comment: Linked files (speed_test_example.html, speed_test.js) are not not found. It leads to broken pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your marker, you can specify where the InfoWindow should be anchored, like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  'position': latLng,
  'icon': markerImage,
  'anchorPoint': new google.maps.Point(x, y)
});
```

where x and y are the x and y offset from the marker's position.

Note: google.maps.MarkerImage is no longer used. Use Icon instead.